# Laravel - relations from pivot table.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have those 4 tables:

```
Products (id, ...)

Params (id, ...)

Product_Param (id, product_id, param_id)

Values (product_param_id, value)
```

How can I use eloquent get Values for product?

```
$product->param[0]->values
```

I can use stupid code (i know pivot Product_Param ID) and get all Values from Values.

But how can I do it using eloquent relationships (relation from pivot table)?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Have you read documentation about ["Has Many Through"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relations?